# Simple MySql select statement returns 0 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is rather silly, but i really don't know what's the problem here. I have a table 'profiles' which a column 'country', i filled this table from a tab separated value file and the table view seems to be fine.

Now when executing this query:

```
select * from profiles where country = 'Sweden'
```

Nothing gets returned, although the table has more than a hundred entry with country 'Sweden' and i double checked my spelling.

But when executing this query:

```
select * from profiles where country REGEXP 'Sweden'
```

it returns results as expected.

What's the cause of this ? and how do i fix it ?

Here is some data from the file used to fill the table:

```
0   f   Germany
1   f   Canada
2       Germany
3   m   Mexico
4   m   United States
5   m   United Kingdom
6   m   Finland
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Did you check this sql statement inside phpmyadmin if you are using it

Comment: How about `select * from profiles where trim(country) = 'Sweden' `

Comment: It looks that Country contains trailing spaces, that's why country = 'Sweden' returns false

Comment: Could you please run this: `select HEX(country) from profiles where country REGEXP 'Sweden' LIMIT 1` and post the result?

Comment: Result : Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0061 sec)

+Options : Hex(country) = 53776564656E0D

Comment: Your string has a trailing carriage return.

Comment: Try this query first and check what is the table collation `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'profiles'\G`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with like operator.

select * from profiles WHERE country LIKE '%Sweden%'

Answer (score 0):

Try with [TRIM](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php) function if any leading or trailing space in country field

```
select * from profiles where TRIM(country) = 'Sweden'
```

OR

```
select * from profiles where TRIM(country) LIKE 'Sweden'
```

OR

```
select * from profiles where country LIKE '%Sweden%'
```

OR check for carrige return value in field list

```
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE country REGEXP "\r\n";
```

Comment: Is this the correct syntax ?
i tried using it, it didn't work (no syntax errors .. but still no results)

Comment: Yes this is correct syntax but in your country field there is `\n` that's why it does not return any value

Comment: i think in this case trim won't be needed right ? since i'll be using LIKE '%Sweden%' anyways

Comment: If you want to check carriage return value then check 4th last query

Comment: Is this slower than using only TRIM (without LIKE) ?

Comment: I don't know but I suggest to you your country field contains carrige return values so remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If your filter data types in character it's best to use operator such as `LIKE`.

```
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE upper(country) LIKE upper('Sweden');
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM `profiles` WHERE country LIKE 'Sweden' this also returned nothing

Comment: Try adding a character manipulation function such as `upper()` or `lower()` on your filter. Aside from `trim()` other answer suggesting.

Comment: still nothing is returned

Comment: By manual checking, Are you sure the record country `Sweden` exists on your table referring to?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive that Sweden exists on my table.

Comment: I believe `%Sweden%` did the tricked solving your problem after checking above answer?

Answer (score 0):

May be you must have stored 'sweden' with trailing spaces in your table, So just check

select * from profiles where TRIM(country) = 'Sweden'

REGEX operator lists rows with 'Sweden' anywhere in it

EG: Sweden_ , __Sweden,   Sweden.

Comment: I tried the TRIM method, but to no avail. It seems like the only solution that worked for me is to use LIKE + % % operators

Comment: using `like %%` is a bad choice it will never use index and for large data set the query time will be really slow.